# Can't find formula to calculate speedup from parallelism

Tags: parallelism-amdahl

I have this problem where I don't really understand the mechanics of speedup.

I have a program that has 2 execution phases. The first phase takes 1 time unit and can only be executed sequentially. The second phase takes 3 time units to execute, but can be parallelized.

How do I calculate the maximum speedup that I can achieve? I'm not looking for the answer, but the formula I need to calculate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to find an answer but I'm not sure if it's correct.

I use a formula that says:

`Speedup = 1 / (sequentialPercentageTime - (parallelizablePercentageTime / Threads))`

Where thread will be 3, in the case that the parallelizable part is perfectly parallelizable.

This means that:

`Speedup = 1 / (0.25 + (0.75/3))
 Speedup = 1 / (0.25 + 0.25)
 Speedup = 1 / 0.5
 Speedup = 2`

Does this make any sense?